# Docker connection with MySql workbench

Tags: reactjs, docker, flask

I have made a reactjs app and backend with flask I'm having a database in MYSQL workbench.I had made a docker container for flask and reactjs app. I want to connect the database with flask for APIs

this is my `docker-compose` file

[image]

Comment: Hello, please refer to this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to provide a minimal-reproducible-example. Can you please include your `docker-compose` file and any other related codes.

Comment: @NcXNaV I've attached

Comment: Hi, do you mean you're trying to access host mysql database from docker-container?

Comment: @NcXNaV yes i am trying to do that only